# I want to prevent 3 consecutive enter keys in a textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want two things to happen in the same textarea:

- the first, I can do: prevent 2 consecutive spaces
- the second, I need help with: prevent 3 consecutive Enter Keys.

Here is my html code:

```
onkeypress="return ignoreConsecutiveSpaces(event);"
```

here is my javascript which I know has problems and even part missin but I just can't figure it out:

```
var lastkey4;
var lastkey5;
var lastkey6;
var ignoreChars4 = ' '+String.fromCharCode(0);
var ignoreChars5 = '\r\n'+String.fromCharCode(0);
function ignoreConsecutiveSpacesOr3Enter(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if(ignoreChars4.indexOf(char) >= 0 && ignoreChars4.indexOf(lastkey4) >= 0) {
        lastkey4 = char;
        alert("Do not enter 2 consecutive spaces or enter keys in this form!");
        return false; }
    else {
        lastkey4 = char;
        return true; }
    if(ignoreChars5.indexOf(char) >= 0 && ignoreChars5.indexOf(lastkey5) >= 0 ) {
        lastkey5 = char;
        if(ignoreChars5.indexOf(char) >= 0 && ignoreChars5.indexOf(lastkey5) >= 0 && ignoreChars5.indexOf(lastkey6) >= 0 ) {
        lastkey6 = char;
        alert("Do not enter 3 consecutive enter keys in this form!");
        return false; }
    else {
        return true; }
    
    }
```

I know I am not gonna be able to do this one on my own, I am gonna need a completed code :( Anyone help? :P

The lastkey4 -lastkey6 are numbered for a reason, other javascript files.

===================

EDIT (after reply)

Here is my edited code that still doesn't work:

```
let EnterKeys = 0;
let SpaceKeys = 0;
const MaxEnter = 3;
const MaxSpace = 3;
var lastkey4;
var ignoreChars4 = '\r\n'+String.fromCharCode(0);
var ignoreChars5 = ' '+String.fromCharCode(0);
function ignoreBoth(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if(ignoreChars4.indexOf(char) >= 0 ) {
        EnterKeys = EnterKeys + 1 ;
        if EnterKeys = MaxEnter {
        alert("Do not enter 3 consecutive enter keys in this form!");
        return false; }
    else {
        lastkey4 = char;
        return true; }    
    }
    if(ignoreChars5.indexOf(char) >= 0 ) {
        SpaceKeys = SpaceKeys + 1 ;
        if SpaceKeys = SpaceEnter {
        alert("Do not enter 3 consecutive spaces in this form!");
        return false; }
    else {
        lastkey4 = char;
        return true; }    
    }
}
```